# Why whenever I resize the picture it's making my other elements move

Tags: html, css

Why whenever I resize the picture it's making my other elements move despite having enough space and having a completely different container.

I had this #content container and #picture container and they are both display as inline-block and they are somewhat in the same row of the page and for some reason whenever I resize my img in my #pic container it also pushes my #container downward despite having completely different container and having enough size to go on. What possibly cause this?

Here is my code

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: sans-serif;
/*  border: 1px solid red; */
}

header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
    background: black;
}

header a#logo {
    color: floralwhite;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2em;
    font-weight: 900;
    margin-left: 2rem;
    margin-top: 8px;
}

header ul {
    margin-right: 2rem;
    height: 80px;
}

header ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 8px;
    margin-top: 1rem;
/*  border: 1px solid red; */
    padding: 8px;
}

header ul li a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 900;
    font-size: 1rem;
    color: floralwhite;
    padding: 8px;
    transition: outline 0.2s, color 0.2s, background 0.2s;
}

header ul li a:hover, header ul li a#active {
    outline: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
    background: floralwhite;
}

div#content {
    margin-left: 8rem;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 4rem;
    position: relative;

}

div#content h1, div#content h2 {
    font-weight: 900;
}

div#content h2 {
    margin-top: -15px;
    text-indent: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

div#content div#content2 {
    width: 400px;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
    text-indent: 5px;
}

div#content::after {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    width: 3%;
    background: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: -4rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
}

span#pic, span#pic img {
    height: 250px;
    margin-left: 8rem;
/*  margin-top: ; */
    border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title> Andri Quin </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Portfolio.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="letter-a.png">
</head>
<body>  
    <header>
        <a href="#" id="logo"> Andri </a>
        <ul>
            <li> <a href="Portfolio.html" id="active"> Home </a> </li>
            <li> <a href=""> Info </a> </li>
            <li> <a href=""> About </a> </li>
        </ul>
    </header>

    <div id="content">
        <h1> Hi! Im Andri Quin </h1>
        <h2> Student Web Developer </h2>
        <div id="content2">
            <p> Im a student aspiring to be a fullstack web deveoper in the near future. I also studying game development as I love playing game as well.Please look forward my work in the near future. </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <span id="pic">
        <img src="letter-a.png">
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Here some picture:

[Before resizing the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnr7V.png)
[After resizing the picture for some reason my content on the left side was pushed down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFcuR.png)
[letter-a.png - the img I used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UBho.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be because you've set your `<div class="content">`'s display to `inline-block`. That makes it inline, and therefore, it gets aligned on the baseline, just like the `<span>` containing your image.

When the image grows higher than the content, so does its containing `<span>`. This pushes the baseline down to the bottom of the image, and your `<div>` follows the movement to stay aligned to the baseline.

To solve it, just wrap both in a container that you'll set to `display: flex` in the `row` direction, like in the below example. If you set its class name to "flex-wrapper", then you only need to add the following css:

```css
.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

*(I'm allowing the flex to wrap here to give you some kind of a fluid design, and keep the look closer to what you previously had)*

And here is a snippet illustrating that (please view it in "full page", or else the wrapping in the flex won't let you apreciate its effect):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  /*  border: 1px solid red;*/
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  background: black;
}

header a#logo {
  color: floralwhite;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 2em;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-left: 2rem;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

header ul {
  margin-right: 2rem;
  height: 80px;
}

header ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 8px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  /*  border: 1px solid red;*/
  padding: 8px;
}

header ul li a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: floralwhite;
  padding: 8px;
  transition: outline 0.2s, color 0.2s, background 0.2s;
}

header ul li a:hover,
header ul li a#active {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  color: black;
  background: floralwhite;
}

div#content {
  margin-left: 8rem;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 4rem;
  position: relative;
}

div#content h1,
div#content h2 {
  font-weight: 900;
}

div#content h2 {
  margin-top: -15px;
  text-indent: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

div#content div#content2 {
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-indent: 5px;
}

div#content::after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  width: 3%;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: -4rem;
  margin-left: 2rem;
}

span#pic,
span#pic img {
  height: 250px;
  margin-left: 8rem;
  /*  margin-top: ;*/
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.flex-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title> Andri Quin </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Portfolio.css">
  <link rel="icon" href="letter-a.png">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <a href="#" id="logo"> Andri </a>
    <ul>
      <li> <a href="Portfolio.html" id="active"> Home </a> </li>
      <li> <a href=""> Info </a> </li>
      <li> <a href=""> About </a> </li>
    </ul>
  </header>

  <div class="flex-wrapper">

    <div id="content">
      <h1> Hi! Im Andri Quin </h1>
      <h2> Student Web Developer </h2>
      <div id="content2">
        <p> Im a student aspiring to be a fullstack web deveoper in the near future. I also studying game development as I love playing game as well.Please look forward my work in the near future. </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <span id="pic">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8UBho.png">
    </span>
  
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```